# This mysql syntax is not correct. What's wrong with it?

Tags: mysql

This code doesn't work on mysql:

```
update member
set member.xy = memba.surba
from memba
where member.id =memba.id
```

The code below0 works:

```
update member inner join memba on member.id =memba.id
set member.xy = memba.surba
```

Could you please explain what's wrong with the first code?

Comment: Well, "what doesn't work"? And where could one go to review syntax understood by MySQL? (Hint: it shouldn't be SO.) Also, please put some effort into questions...

Comment: what I wonder is why you care considering the second one works? Isn't this like asking why update member set magic = true doesn't work? If the syntax is wrong then it's wrong.

Comment: I think user1040364 is not so fluent in english, which isn't a crime...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple-table syntax:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_references
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
```

It would seem that you have a FROM clause that is not part of the update statement in MySQL.

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html